# Showing that every smooth embedded Torus has a point with negative curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm having a bit of trouble formally proving the following question from differential geometry:

Show that every smooth embedded torus in $\mathbb R^3$ has a point with negative curvature.

I know intuitively that this is true. If we look at the "inner" portion of the torus it is basically something similar to the saddle surface, which is a surface whose curves from the tangent plane go into two different directions. Hence it would make sense why there must exist a single point say $p$ in our torus $T$ that has negative curvature.

I am just a unsure on how to go about the proof formally. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem#Interpretation_and_significance , if you can use the Gauss-Bonnet theorem and Euler characteristic.

Comment: That wikipedia link is sort of vague, but as far as I can tell it certainly does *not* address every smooth embedded torus in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Yeah, that link isn't quite sufficient. But $\chi=0$ and Gauss-Bonnet tell you that if there are points of positive curvature, there must be points of negative curvature. Now show that every compact surface in $\Bbb R^3$ must have a point of positive curvature.